# Spivak: Prove $\log{b}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x(b^{1/x}-1)$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, logarithms, exponential-function

The following problem is from Ch. 18 in Spivak's *Calculus*. My calcuations differed from the solution manual, and I'd like to know if they are correct.

> 17 *(d)  Prove $\log{b}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x(b^{1/x}-1)$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x(b^{1/x}-1)=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{b^{1/x}-1}{1/x}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}\log{b}}-1}{1/x}=\frac{0}{0}$$

By L'Hopital's Rule

$$=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}\log{b}}\cdot \log{b} \cdot\frac{(-1)}{x^2}}{\frac{(-1)}{x^2}}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \log{b} \cdot e^{\frac{1}{x}\cdot \log{b}}=\log{b}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

$$...=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{b^{1/x}-1}{1/x}$$

Yes, your work is correct.

On your first line, it will be simpler if define $\frac{1}{x}=t$ and let $t\to0^+$

Comment: Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Answer (score 0):

We know that:
$$e^{f(x)}-1\,\,\sim\,\, f(x)$$
when $f(x)\to 0$ for $x\to x_0$.

Also, we can write:
$$b^{\frac1x}-1=e^{\log(b)\frac1x}-1\,\,\sim\,\,\frac{\log(b)}{x}$$

So, your limit becomes:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x(b^{1/x}-1)\,\sim\,\,\lim_{x\to 0}x\cdot\frac{\log(b)}{x}=\log(b)$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following, for $n \geq 1$:
\begin{align} 
x^n \, \left( b^{a/x^n} -1 \right) &= x^n \, \left(e^{\frac{a}{x^n} \, \ln b} - 1 \right) \\
&= x^n \, \left(\frac{a \, \ln b}{x^n} + \frac{a^2 \, \ln^2 b}{2 \, x^{2n}} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^{3 n}}\right) \right) \\
&= a \, \ln b + \frac{a^2 \, \ln^2 b}{2 \, x^{n}} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2 n}}\right)
\end{align}
which gives the limit as
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \, x^n \, \left( b^{a/x^n} -1 \right) = a \, \ln b. $$